# SQL query add new custom row dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is my SQL query which currently outputs this result:

[image]

SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS noofuser,
    [DateTime], [Date], [hour],
    [Company]
FROM 
    LMT2_lmutilserverLicenseuser
```

But, I need to add extra row called 'Total' based on a column 'DateTime' as shown in the below table.

[image]

Comment: total based on what??

Comment: What are the types of your date and datetime columns?

Comment: @nikhilsugandh total of 'Count' Column based on 'DateTime' column

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen type of Date column is Date and  'DateTime' column is Varchar

Comment: @pankajbawdane, lookup for mysql rollup operator.

Comment: Sample data and desired results provide as text, not as an images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining the query with a group by should work, haven't been able to run but this should give the result. You can insert the result of your query in temp table (thus count(*) gets its own column) and then just do another `group by` on the temp table

```
SELECT cnt, date_time, date , hr ,company 
FROM LMT2_lmutilserverLicenseuserTemp 
UNION 
SELECT SUM(cnt), date_time, MAX(date) , MIN(hr) , 'tot' AS company 
FROM LMT2_lmutilserverLicenseuserTemp
GROUP BY date_time
ORDER BY date_time
```

Comment: Error:Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Comment: Yikes....yes you cannot do sum (count(*)) as the exception says, but the logic is still same, see updated ans